# sql - conversion error when changing 'and' to 'or'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a database table in sql server 2008.  My query is breaking for a reason that is unknown to me:

```
select release_id, url_id,tt_projectid, release_title, tech_area, current_state,     dateadd(ss,last_built,'12/31/1969 20:00:00') as recent_Date,
        autobuild_count, manualbuild_count, bcm_build_count, config_count, force_count, transition_only_count,
        auto_integ_count,last_auto_integ,dateadd(ss,integ_complete_date,'12/31/1969 20:00:00') as integ_date

        from tablename 
        where (auto_integ_count > 0
        and MONTH(last_auto_integ) = '1'
        and YEAR(last_auto_integ) = '2013')
        and (release_id > 36000)

        order by release_id desc
```

The above query works fine, but when I change the last line of the where close from 'and' to 'or' I get this conversion error:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

I'm puzzled as to why changing

```
'and (release_id > 36000)'
```

to

```
'or (release_id > 36000)'
```

would cause such an error

Comment: It seems likelier that you're getting this error because of `YEAR() = '2013'` or `MONTH() = '1'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is because `last_auto_integ` is being stored as a string rather than as a date.  These lines in the `where` clause are not being executed with the `and` -- by happenstance -- because none occur when `release_id > 360000`.

From what I can see, there are no other places in the query where you might be converting a string to a date format.

You can identify these values using:

```
select last_auto_integ
from tablename 
where isdate(last_auto_integ) = 0 and last_auto_integ is not null
```

You can fix the problem in the query by using `case`:

```
where month(case when isdate(last_auto_integ) = 1 then last_auto_integ end) = 1 and
      year(case when isdate(last_auto_integ) = 1 then last_auto_integ end) = 2013
```

Or, you can just use `substring()` to extract the month and year from whatever date format you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Because when you change `AND` to `OR` you are getting a lot more rows returned, and one of these other expressions is failing:

```
dateadd(ss,integ_complete_date,'12/31/1969 20:00:00')

MONTH(last_auto_integ)

YEAR(last_auto_integ)
```

Answer (score 0):

With only `AND`, it doesn't need to evaluate the other expressions for rows whose release_id is <= 36000, so it's not encountering the strings that are causing the problem on date conversion.